# Problem with implementation of RTCMultiConnection (stream Audio) in Ionic 3.9.2 IOS version

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, webrtc

I have a problem with the implementation of RTCMultiConnection (stream Audio) in Ionic 3.9.2. Unlike the Android version, where everything works fine, the IOS application works only one way - when user connects to an existing stream app receives audio sounds from it. If user starts new stream, nothing is working, even popup asking for permissions to the microphone is missing. The terminal does not display any errors. Has anyone of you faced such a problem?

I've also implemented this plugin
https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/Building.md

[index.html]

```
<body>
  <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      if ((typeof device !== "undefined") && device.platform == 'iOS'){
        cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals();
      }
    }, false);
  </script>

</body>
```

[home.ts]

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform) {

  }

  clickBtn(){
    this.requestPermissions().then(() => {
      this.createConnection();
    });
  }

  createConnection() {
    const RTCMultiConnection = window['RTCMultiConnection'];
    const connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
    connection.socketURL = 'https://apilink:9001/';
    connection.socketMessageEvent = 'RTC-audio';
    connection.session = {audio: true, video: false, oneway: true};
    connection.bandwidth = {audio: 64};
    connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {OfferToReceiveAudio: true,OfferToReceiveVideo: false};
    connection.iceServers.push({
      urls: 'turn:217.182.77.219:3478',
      credential: 'credential_password',
      username: 'rtc_username'
    });

    connection.onPeerStateChanged = this.onPeerStateChanged;
    connection.onleave = this.onleave;
    connection.onstream = this.onstream;
    connection.onstreamended = this.onstreamended;
    connection.onRoomFull = this.onRoomFull;
    connection.onMediaError = this.onMediaError;
    connection.openOrJoin('Channel12345');
  }

  onPeerStateChanged = event => {
    console.log('onPeerStateChanged', event);
  }

  onleave = event => {
    console.log('onleave', event);
  }

  onstream = event => {
    console.log('onstream', event);
  }

  onstreamended = event => {
    console.log('onstreamended', event);
  }

  onRoomFull = event => {
    console.log('onRoomFull', event);
  }

  onMediaError = event => {
    console.log('onMediaError', event);
  }

  requestPermissions() {
    if(!this.platform.is('cordova'))
      return Promise.reject('not cordova');

    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      return this.requestAndroidPermissions();
    }
    else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      console.log("PLATFORM IOS")
      return Promise.resolve(true)
    }
  }

  requestAndroidPermissions() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const {permissions} = window['cordova'].plugins;
      permissions.requestPermissions([
          permissions.CAMERA,
          permissions.MICROPHONE,
          permissions.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
          permissions.RECORD_AUDIO,
          permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
          permissions.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
        ],
        ok => resolve(ok),
        error => reject(error)
      );
    })
  }
}
```

config.xml

```
   <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <hook src="hooks/iosrtc-swift-support.js" type="after_platform_add" />
        <preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-ENABLE_BITCODE" value="NO" />
        <config-file parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>App uses your microphone to make calls.</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>App uses your camera to make video calls.</string>
        </config-file>
...
  </platform>
```

I want to add ability to start new stream on IOS, because now it's not working.